# TSQL SET command not working inside EXEC statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, exec

I am trying to run the below script in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1

EXEC('SET '+@counter+' = '+@counter+' + 1')
```

However, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '1'-

I have been troubleshooting for days but gotten nowhere - I guess most likely TSQL simply does not accept this inside an EXEC command, but what could I potentially replace it with?

This is a part of a larger script where the above MUST be inside an EXEC statement in order for the rest to work..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. The code you provide will translate in `SET 1 = 1 + 1` ? `SET` should be followed by a variable starting with `@`. So the error you are seeing is expected.

Comment: I am just incrementing the @counter variable. And the SET command is followed by @, but I think you have to stringify queries/scripts in EXEC if you're not executing a stored procedure? But in a string you call the variable using '+@counter+'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to working for a number of reasons.

Let's start with what you have:

```sql
DECLARE @counter INT = 1

EXEC('SET '+@counter+' = '+@counter+' + 1')
```

`EXEC` is expecting a string inside the parenthesis, yet you have an `int` (the variable `@counter`), so that is your first problem. Oddly, however, you aren't getting a conversion error here; it seems that `@counter` *is* being interpreted as its value (`1`), rather than [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) being applied first. (If you try `SELECT 'SET '+@counter+' = '+@counter+' + 1'` you'll get the error *"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SET ' to data type int."*).

Even *if* the query successfully got past that hurdle, that would cause another error because the query becomes:

```sql
SET 1 = 1 + 1
```

Obviously that isn't going to work, `1` is `1`, no other number.

Next, a variable declared *outside* of the scope of a "dynamic" statement can't be referenced inside it. Let's take the following:

```sql
DECLARE @Varible int = 1;

EXEC (N'SELECT @Variable;');
```

This returns the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Variable".

If you are using a "dynamic" statement (your statement isn't dynamic at all), then you need to parametrise the variables. This is why you shouldn't be using `EXEC ({SQL Statement})` and should be using `sys.sp_executesql`.

So, for the above, you get:

```sql
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SET @Variable = @Variable + 1;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Variable int OUTPUT',@Variable = @counter OUTPUT;

SELECT @Counter;
```

As I mentioned, that is all pointless, as there's nothing dynamic in the above, and your query should just be:

```sql
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
SET @counter = @counter + 1;
```

*Of course, none of this even goes on to address things like how to **safely** inject objects into a dynamic statement, but that isn't what this question is about. As I mention, the dynamic statement here is redundant, as it isn't dynamic, and it's not that required deferred parsing (such as when you `ALTER` a table to add a column, and then try to reference that column in  the same batch).*

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script below, it'll throw an error like

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Must declare the scalar variable "@counter".

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @counter INT = 1
    EXEC('SET @counter = '+ @counter+' + 1')
END
```

**WHY?**

Because `dynamic SQL` is a ***different scope*** to the outer.

So can try this way (using output)

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(50) = 'SELECT @counter2 =' + CAST(@counter + 1 AS VARCHAR(100))
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@counter2 int out', @counter out
SELECT @counter
```

Comment: Hmm, it works, but I disagree with injecting the variable, when it should be parametrised. :)

Comment: Well, I pointed out the problem `dynamic SQL is a different scope to the outer` at least. Furthermore, the solution the same as you.

Comment: It's not the same when you're injecting the value, @Phong ;) Though there's nothing "wrong" with 2 answers having the same *rough* solution provided they are posted at similar times. Most user on [so] understand that 2 (or more) people can be typing similar answers at the same time, and thus even if someone "beat them to it" will submit as they put the time and effort into submitting the answer. *Though, if a question gets lots of them at the same time (like 4 or 5) it's a strong indication the question likely has a dupe candidate.*

Comment: Ok. It makes sense. Happy coding. Cheer! @Larnu